# Get the closest img src inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the src of an image inside the **closest** div with the class name "asd" but I keep getting "undefined" returned. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div class="asd">
     <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="test">
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="show()" >test</button>
```

Javascript

```
 function show(){
     var url = jQuery(this).closest('.asd').find("img").attr("src");  
     alert(url);
  }
```

This works: `$('.asd').find('img').attr('src');` but it's not what I need. I need it be the closest div. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this` in your code refers to `window` object and `closest` selects the closest _parent_ element.

Comment: Read [the documentation for `closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: If the `<button>` is always *immediately* following the `<div>`, you might find jQuery's [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prev()` will do the trick:

```
jQuery("#btn").click(function(){
     var url = jQuery(this).prev('.asd').find("img").attr("src");
     alert(url);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uvxosp7e/

Comment: thanks, that worked, but what if I wanted to do this without clicking the button? After the page has loaded. I tried jQuery's .ready() but had no luck, it returned undefined

Comment: It returned as "undefined". Same happened in the fiddle. EDIT: Weird, in firefox it works, in chrome it returns undefined EDIT2: Nevermind, I CTRL+F5, it's working now, thanks

Comment: Right.  One of the core concepts of jQuery is that of Selectors - a way to identify and select elements.  Somehow you need to identify the element you want to do this to.  Suggest reading: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thanks, for the info, I removed my previous comment because I didn't think I was making much sense. I was a bit confused, I'll read up on that.

Answer (score 0):

What about this selector then

```
$('.asd > img').attr('src');
```

..?

Document for the jQuery child selector: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery's [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) selectors. I think that's what you're looking for.

Essentially, they both get the immediately following and preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements respectively.

Answer (score 0):

this is referring to the window object, you need to pass a reference:

```
<button type="button" onclick="show(this)" >test</button>
```

Then, you can do this: (`closest` travels up in the dom tree, not its siblings )

```
function show(button){
     var url = jQuery(button).prev('.asd').find("img").attr("src");  
     console.log(url);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked too, but what if I wanted to remove the button and do this automatically after the page has loaded?

Comment: well, you could do a `$("button").each(function(){show(this)})` and then in the show function `jQuery(button).remove()`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to pass `this` as parameter:

```
<button type="button" onclick="show(this)" >test</button>
```

and in **js**:

```
window.show = function(obj){
    var url = $(obj).prev().children("img").attr("src");
}
```

[**fiddle using prev**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4rcgmsk/3/)

Alternative if you want to use `closest` then you have to change your html structure to following:

```
<div class="asd">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="test" />
    <button type="button" onclick="show(this)" >test</button>
</div>
```

**js**

```
window.show = function(obj){
    var url = $(obj).closest(".asd").children("img").attr("src");
}
```

[**fiddle using closest**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4rcgmsk/8/)

**Ref**

`this` refers to the DOM element.

[.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Thanks, I understand now I was using closest wrong.